# Why is generated override code for generic method incorrect?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, optional-parameters

I have an abstract generic class

```
public abstract class Foo<TType>
```

with an abstract method

```
public abstract object DoSomething(TType arg = default(TType)) {}
```

Now, the inherited class

```
public class BabyFoo : Foo<string>
```

when I want to override DoSomething and start typing "override " to get the intellisense/generator to write a method skeleton I expected

```
public override object DoSomething(string arg = default(string))
```

or even

```
public override object DoSomething(string arg = null)
```

but it literally comes up with

```
public override object DoSomething(string arg = default(TType))
```

My initial thought is it is a VS2010 bug since optional params are new to c#, but can anybody tell me if there is perhaps a real reason why (reference types vs value types??) the IDE generates this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify:

```
public abstract class Foo<TType>
{
    public abstract object DoSomething(TType arg = default(TType));
}

public class BabyFoo : Foo<string>
{
    // Expected:
    public override object DoSomething(string arg = default(string))
    // Actual:
    public override object DoSomething(string arg = default(TType));
}
```

Unless there's something I'm missing, it's quite simply a bug in the Visual Studio IDE / code-gen. Changing the method signature to the "expected" one results in code that will compile, as the "actual" one refuses to compile thanks to being clearly invalid.

Having tried a few different types for `TType` as well as things like the `where TType : new()` constraint, I couldn't get VS to generate valid code with your `DoSomething` method.

**Congratulations - you've (probably) found a bug in Visual Studio =)**

There are always edge cases when it comes to code generation, I logged [one for Visual Basic 2005/2008](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/388068/wiring-up-events-using-events-in-properties-window-generates-invalid-code) a long time ago that was resolved WONT FIX as it was a *really* obscure one comparatively. Hopefully this one'll be fixed though!

Comment: Much neater than mine indeed!

Comment: haha - Workarounds: 0, closed as: won't fix. Unlucky. But yes this is not really problematic. I just got to wondering if I was missing something.  Also tried some variations with no success, and that's how this question ended up here :-) cheers